# URL of image tag not always exist

Tags: html

I have a img tag, with a src attribute of an URL, so sometimes it can get an image from it, but not always and It'll still be good, so how can I get rid of that error on browsers? Thanks!

The error: Failed to load Resource error (I want this error to dissapear, but It is correct that maybe this URL does not exist).

My img tag if you want (pretty normal). Is there any way to do it? Thanks!

```
<img id="imgUser" src="<%=lUserPath%>" alt="">
```

Comment: Can you check to see if `<%=lUserPath%>` resolves and if it does, only then add the `<img>` to your document?

Comment: I mean for example, user1 will have an image to user/user.jpg, path will be correct and image will display, but maybe user2 doesn't have a img, this URL will give error, but for me it's ok if he doesn't have one, so I want to get rid of this error.

Comment: Why does it matter if your browser (correctly) shows a 404 error in the console? Your users will not see it.

Comment: I don't know mate, it's ugly to always see this error when this happens, i was wondering if there would be a way to trick browser maybe with a null path or something

Comment: There is no way to prevent the browser from causing a 404 error after issuing a failed request without *not* issuing it.

Comment: Ok, now I know it's impossible to avoid that, thank you guys!

Comment: _"it's ugly to always see this error when this happens"_ - Don't open the console. Problem solved 